# Laravel 5.5 wildcard sudomain not working on live server

Tags: laravel, subdomain, wildcard, shared-hosting

I'm making a laravel app and part of it is users been able to create a page which I want to have as subdomain. On my localhost this works fine. But immediately I uploaded to a live server, I got this

**This site can’t be reached
sub.domain.com’s server IP address could not be found.**

I've set up a wildcard subdomain and yet nothing seems to be working...

Comment: This is a DNS issue, your request doesn't even reach Laravel. Your subdomain needs to resolve to your webservers IP.

Comment: Is there anything I can don about this?

Comment: Part of the reason I said it works on localhost... so I'm not sure it has anything to do with the laravel app itself

Comment: You need to edit your DNS zone and add the subdomain records. There likely is backend for this at your providers site. Also, if using VHosts, the webserver needs to be configured to also route requests with that hostname to your app, but that's step 2.

Comment: I've added the record already... still not working. How do I get to the Vhosts file?

Comment: Same error? If you just added it, your DNS server may still give an outdated/cached response for a few hours. Verify at https://dns.google.com